# How to return an array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to return an array but don't know how to do this, here is how it looks

```
CGPoint position[] = {
    CGPointMake(500, 200),             
    CGPointMake(500, 200)                         
};

return position;
```

But I get an error of incompatible result. Any way around this error? Need to return multiple positions.

Comment: Do you really want an array like that? It is usually better to have an NSMutableArray instead of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
NSArray *position = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(500, 200)],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(600, 300)],
                     nil];
```

for getting the values from array

```
for(int i=0; i<[position count]; i++) {
    NSValue *value = [position objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint point = [value CGPointValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint(point);
}
```

Comment: it will point the first object in the array. If you want the second object means NSValue *value = [position objectAtIndex:1];

Comment: Is there a way of returning both of them at same time?

Answer (score 0):

With UIKit Apple added support for CGPoint to NSValue, so you can do:

```
NSArray *points = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(5.5, 6.6)],
                     [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(7.7, 8.8)],
                     nil];
```

List as many [NSValue] instances as you have CGPoint, and end the list in nil. All objects in this structure are auto-released.

On the flip side, when you're pulling the values out of the array:

```
NSValue *val = [points objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [val CGPointValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `NSArray` and since CGPoint is a struct you can return it the C way

```
CGPoint *position = malloc(sizeof(CGPoint)*2);
position[0] = CGPointMake(500,200);
position[1] = CGPointMake(500,200);
return position;
```

although the drawback is that the calling function doesn't know the number of elements in the array, you may need to tell this in some other manner.

also you need to free the returning array once you are done with it using free();

although using `NSArray/NSMutableArray` is more convenient.